# Scrape CDC vaccination data using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape the vaccination data from the below CDC website:
https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/#vaccinations

I have tried querySelectorAll but no luck. Can anyone help take a look? Much appreciated!

```
Sub useClassnames()

Dim appIE As Object
Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

With appIE
    .navigate "https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/#vaccinations"
    .Visible = False
End With

Do While appIE.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop

Set allRowOfData = appIE.document.getElementById("maincontent")
Debug.Print allRowOfData.innerHTML

'Set element = appIE.document.querySelectorAll(".container mt-5")
'For Each elements In element
' Debug.Print elements
'Next elements

'For Each element In allRowOfData
'Debug.Print element
'Next element

End Sub
```

Comment: Content at `maincontent` is blank suggesting data is Javascript rendered and not static HTML content. However, consider using their [data API page](https://data.cdc.gov/Case-Surveillance/COVID-19-Case-Surveillance-Public-Use-Data/vbim-akqf) (from link in lower right) which may contain more than single data points. CSV, TSV, XML, types are available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have, just change your worksheet name or number :)

```
Option Explicit
Const updatedCol = 1
Const dosesDistributedColVal = 2
Const peopleInicVaccColVal = 3



Sub useClassnames()
    
    'declare worksheet variable and set headers
    Dim targetWsh As Worksheet: Set targetWsh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    targetWsh.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Last Update"
    targetWsh.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Doses Distributed"
    targetWsh.Cells(1, 3).Value = "People Initiating Vaccination"
    
    Dim lstRegisterRow As Long: lstRegisterRow = targetWsh.Range("A" & targetWsh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    'open IE and navigate to site
    Dim appIE As InternetExplorer: Set appIE = New InternetExplorer
    appIE.navigate "https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/#vaccinations"
    appIE.Visible = False
    While appIE.Busy = True Or appIE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
    
    Dim oHtmlDoc As HTMLDocument: Set oHtmlDoc = appIE.document
    Dim oHtmlElementColl As IHTMLElementCollection
    
    'Get and write last update date
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02")) 'wait 2 secs to avoid error, if recieve error, add seconds as needed
    Set oHtmlElementColl = oHtmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("small")
    targetWsh.Cells(lstRegisterRow, updatedCol) = oHtmlElementColl(0).innerHTML
  
    'Get and write Doses Distributed and People Initiating Vaccination
    Set oHtmlElementColl = oHtmlDoc.GetElementsByClassName("card-number")
    targetWsh.Cells(lstRegisterRow, dosesDistributedColVal) = oHtmlElementColl(0).innerText
    targetWsh.Cells(lstRegisterRow, peopleInicVaccColVal) = oHtmlElementColl(1).innerText
    
    appIE.Quit

End Sub
```

[image]